# Refresh a dataframe evey day in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, sentiment-analysis

I am doing a sentiment analysis app in R shiny. The problem is that I need new tweets evey day to add more information to the analysis.

Now I have the tweets from 12th November to 25th November but I would like that every day the dataframe of tweets got bigger adding the tweets from the last day automatically.

I've been trying with functions *invalidateLater* and *reactivetimer* but it doesnt work because when I run the app, it automatically begins by searching for new tweets instead of showing the historical results and then search for the most recent tweets

My code in the server looks like this:

```
data<-reactive({
    #filtering depending on the values of the ui's inputs
    (such as type of tweet, type of user...) 
  })
 output<-renderPlot({
   datos<-data()
   (Plots...)
 })
```

As I said before, I've created a *recentdata* reactive value with *invalidateLater* but I haven't been able to do it properly...

Comment: Its probably best if you have an external Rscript doing this (via Cron Job or a bat script with task scheduler) and possibly dumping into a file or a database. You can then use `reactiveFileReader` or a DB connection to read the data

Comment: You could do with an observe() statement, if you create reactive variable that store time.  There maybe reactive timer would be of use.